# in php when reading content of a .txt file using $fileName, how would I add a user sessionID

Tags: php

Currently, I am doing this. the file name is challenge-1.txt I would like to replace "1" with session ID. This can be echoed with
`<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["id"]); ?>`
$filename = 'challenge-1.txt'; this line needs to be doing some thing like $fileName  =
'challenge-' session_id()' . ".txt";  But I'm not getting it.

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
header("location: login.php");
exit;
}

?>
<?php
$filename = 'challenge-1.txt';
$handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
$current = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
?> 

<p class="details";><?php echo 'You have <strong>'.$current.'</strong> coins saved!'; ?></p>
```

Comment: It looks like you have a couple of typos in your solution.  Try `$filename = 'challenge-' . session_id() . '.txt';`  (Also, you'll obviously need to add some code to check if that file exists before you attempt to read from it).  Alternatively, instead of storing this value in a file, you could just store it in $_SESSION?

Comment: Yeah I also don't understand the logic of storing a value assoicated with a session ID somewhere other than the session itself.

Comment: Yes $_SESSION is my choice and thank you my typos were giving me grief.  I am how using $filename = 'challenge-' . ($_SESSION["loggedin"]) . '.txt'; and all is well.